# How do I prevent users from accessing Low, Medium, High, etc. services for our Oracle Autonomous Database (ADB)?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

ADB users can connect to the database with any database service like LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH as listed in [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/connect-predefined-generic.html#GUID-E49773B3-6C07-4F6F-906B-42705D237523). How can I prevent specific user from accessing these services?

Disclaimer: I am a product manager for Autonomous Database.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and disclose that you are "Director, Product Management, Autonomous Database"

Comment: @MT0 blame me, in most circumstances having that directly in the user profile should suffice?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith See https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion which states "However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers."

Comment: Thanks @MT0 I need to do better in that regard myself then.

Answer (score 0):

Today, this is possible using logon triggers. You can create a logon trigger and block any user from accessing the services you want to block.

Here's an example. In this example, the user SALES will not be able to connect to the HIGH service.

```
create or replace trigger sess_logon
after logon on database
begin
if sys_context('USERENV','SESSION_USER') = 'SALES' and
   sys_context('USERENV','SERVICE_NAME') = 'IAAA8NWXQOHGU3H_SALESDB_high.adwc.oraclecloud.com'
then
    raise_application_error(-20001,'You are not allowed to connect to the HIGH service.');
end if;
END;
/
```

The full service names for HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW to use in this trigger can be found with this query.

```
select name from v$services;
```

Disclaimer: I am a product manager for Autonomous Database.

Comment: You should [edit] your answer and disclose your affiliation that you are "Director, Product Management, Autonomous Database"